# Hide button once product is added to cart

Tags: magento-1.9

We are Providing an option for **"Add to cart" & "Delete"** for each product in **My account** section.

what we need is if that product is added to cart, than we want to **hide** the **"Delete"** button.
[image]

```
<?php
$productId = $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
if (! $quote->hasProductId($productId)) 
{
?>

<a><span>Delete</span></a>

<?php   
}
?>
```

I tried above code, but still "Delete" button visible after click on "Add to cart"

Comment: You can do it in 2 diff ways. 1) If your page is getting reloaded after hitting the add to cart button then you can easily check if product id exists in quote and remove the button by adding display:none to your css. 2) If its using ajax add to cart then do it from jQuery. Both are easy.

Comment: @KingshukDeb page is reloading, i am trying the code in question, but it didt worked for me, can you please check and tell what wrong i did ? or what css code will make it work......

Comment: Try to var dump $quote->hasProductId($productId); line

Comment: @simplysaif i got result :  `bool(false)` after i used `var_dump($quote->hasProductId($productId));`

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($productId)) try this code to check if item is in the cart already.. var dump it

Comment: @simplysaif i got error : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING) in ` when i used `$quote =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemB‌​yProduct($productId)‌​;`

Comment: $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId()); $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote(); if (! $quote->getItemByProduct($productId)) { ?> <a><span>Delete</span></a> <?php }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
 $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote(); 
if (! $quote->getItemByProduct($productId))
 { 
?>
 <a><span>Delete < /span> < /a> 
<?php 
}
?>
```